# no sound on gemini lake with xubuntu

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an Intel Gemini Lake laptop with N4020 Intel CPU. I'm using latest daily xubuntu hirsute with kernel 5.11.0-13, it recognized everything including wifi and bluetooth, but the problem is I haven't had audio at all. Dead silent.

the pavucontrol shows only dummy output, the vumeter below the volume slider is dancing when i play some audio but there is no sound at all from the speaker.
[pavucontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziA2t.png)

the output from aplay -l only shows card0 as HDMI :

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

the output from proc/asound :

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1110000 irq 133
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#2 | grep -i codec
Codec: Intel Geminilake HDMI
```

and the output from lspci only shows this :

```
lspci -nn | grep -i audio
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio [8086:3198] (rev 06)
```

I began searching the solution and unfortunately nothing works including this trick to add options on /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

and include the blacklist for module snd_soc_skl on /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
blacklist snd_soc_skl
```

do a reboot but still no sound from speaker and got dummy output at pavucontrol.

I also try to determined the vid/pid from that lspci as :

```
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=auto vid=8086 pid=3198
```

still got dummy output as well

but when I change the primary to PCH then HDMI :

```
options snd-hda-intel id=PCH,HDMI enable=0,1
```

there is some slight change on aplay -l output as these :

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 2: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

but unfortunately still no sound, the pavucontrol still shows dummy output.

I have ran out of idea for now, and i really hope, maybe someone who experienced something like this could help me. Can somebody help me please?
Thank you very much in advance.